# MySQL & PHP Parameter 1 as Resource

Tags: php, mysql

Alright, PHP is throwing this error at me (in the log) when I run the code mentioned below:

**Error**

> mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in (place) on line 10

**Line 9-11**

```
$queryFP = ("SELECT * FROM db");
$countFP = mysql_num_rows($queryFP);
$aID = rand(1, $countFP);
```

I think it has something to do with the $queryFP's syntax, but I'm not completely sure how to fix it since $queryFP's syntax is the simplest query I've ever seen.

Comment: +1 for the perfectly formed question. Both problem code and error message. Everyone to follow this example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysql_fetch_* expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674312/warning-mysql-fetch-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-error)

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to query the database first.

```
$queryFP = ("SELECT * FROM db");
```

Should be:

```
$queryFP = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db");
```

Comment: Wow, I should have known that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the **[`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)** function, it should be like this:

```
$queryFP = "SELECT * FROM table_name_here";
$queryFP = mysql_query($queryFP) or die(mysql_error());
$countFP = mysql_num_rows($queryFP);
$aID = rand(1, $countFP);
```

Comment: That `or die(..)` stuff is so terrible.

Comment: True, this is just an example and should be avoided at *production* level, good idea to see if there is any error in the query while in *development* :)

Answer (score 0):

As it been said, you're missing mysql_query function.
Though whole approach is wrong. You shouldn't select whole load of ata if you need only number of rows.
So, it must be

```
$sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM db";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error().$sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($res);
$countFP = $row[0];
$aID = rand(1, $countFP);
```

And I hope you won't use $aID for any database related action

Comment: $aID is used to select the row of which needs displayed.

Comment: It actually needs the entire row, not just the number of them, which is why $aID is required.

Comment: @Nik there can be gaps with no ids. `SELECT * FROM db, limit $aID,1` query could do the trick.

Comment: In this very example you don't get any rows. Only number.

Comment: I'm aware, I only posted the necessary code to fix the issue, the next block of code pulls the array of which is required then displays it.

Comment: What should I do then, because this is the only logical way to achieve what the rest of the block does.

Comment: @Nik if you need only ONE random row off the whole table, you need 2 steps: 1. Get the NUMBER of rows. 2. Get ONE random row. First step I posted in my answer and query for the second in the comment.

Comment: Oh, I see, why did you say that I shouldn't use $aID for any database related action?

Comment: @Nik because name of the variable makes me think if `id` database field while you cannot use this random value as id.

Comment: And my main intention was to tell you that you shouldn't request whole table data if you need only number of rows.