# mysql_fetch_array() not working

Tags: php, mysql, email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787097/php-mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given)

I'm trying to send emails to addresses in a database. the addresses are in two parts: a username (aka 'number') and @something.com (aka 'carrier'). so the email address should be 'number' . 'carrier'

my code is below. the mail function works on its own (not in the loop). the error message i am getting is "mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in home/username/public_html/script.php on line 15)

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?
    require_once("PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php");

    // connect to database
    mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password");
    mysql_select_db("username_finalproject_Alerts");

    // prepare query
    $sql = "SELECT number, carrier FROM Alerts";
    // execute query
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        //generate email address
        $email = $row['number'] . $row['carrier'];

        // send mail

        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->Host = "private stmp address";
        $mail->ContentType = 'text/plain';
        $mail->IsHTML(false);
        $mail->SetFrom("private email address");
        $mail->AddAddress($email);
        $mail->Subject = "TRY 1";
        $mail->Body = "testing 1 2 3";
        if ($mail->Send() === false)
            die($mail->ErrorInfo . "\n");
    }

?>
```

Comment: $result is empty and therefore you have this error. Probably you haven't mysql connection. Check mysql status and data connection.

Answer (score 3):

There must be something wrong with your query, can you test it elsewere?

Perhaps you can try to catch the error

`if(!$result)
    {
        echo mysql_error();
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Unless your login to the database is "username" and your password is "password" I think you probably meant

```
mysql_connect("localhost", $username, $password);
```

Not sure if this code is verbatim from yours or you just changed those for privacy but thought it might be worth pointing out.

Comment: oh sorry, i just changed those for privacy. thanks for the suggestion, though.

Answer (score 0):

to make easy you query you can also use: `CONCAT(number, carrier)` which provides you the combine result of both rows in a single result,

the second as the all suggested the use `mysql_query($sql) or die('Error in Query!<br>' . mysql_error());`

so that if the error in your query then you will get the error details through `mysql_error()`

Answer (score 0):

check `mysql_num_rows($rows)>0`

```
    // connect to database
    mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password");
    mysql_select_db("username_finalproject_Alerts");

    // prepare query
    $sql = "SELECT number, carrier FROM Alerts";
    // execute query
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        //generate email address
        $email = $row['number'] . $row['carrier'];

        // send mail

        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->Host = "private stmp address";
        $mail->ContentType = 'text/plain';
        $mail->IsHTML(false);
        $mail->SetFrom("private email address");
        $mail->AddAddress($email);
        $mail->Subject = "TRY 1";
        $mail->Body = "testing 1 2 3";
        if ($mail->Send() === false)
            die($mail->ErrorInfo . "\n");
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score -2):

write like this

```
$email = $row[0] . $row[1];
```

Comment: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource It Means there's a problem in query